# "Suspend" execution, but keep event handlers running?

Tags: vb.net, suspend

Windows 7 Home Premium
Visual Basic

Is there a way to suspend execution of a program, but keep event handlers running?

My Visual Basic console application watches for file events, and handles the events with the familiar event handlers.

Current algorithm:
    1. Create FileSystemWatcher
    2. Set up event handlers
    3. Wait for console input from the user, then exit.

Can I replace the last step with a system call to suspend execution of the foreground, while the event handlers continue reacting to events?

Here's an outline of the code (with many lines removed).

```
    Dim watcher As New FileSystemWatcher()                  'Create a new FileSystemWatcher

    AddHandler watcher.Changed, AddressOf OnChanged         'Add event handler  
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True                      'Begin watching  

    'I wish to replace this with a system call to suspend  
    'execution, but keep the event handlers running.  
    While Chr(Console.Read()) <> "q"c                       'Wait for the user to quit  
    End While
```

Comment: I think what you're really looking for is how to create a background process?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to create a service. To do that, the easiest way is probably to create a new project based on the "Windows Service" template and migrate your existing code.

MSDN docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412.aspx